# loading properties files during maven build spring profiles

Tags: java, spring, maven

We have an application spring boot and we set environment variables, so when we we try to build our app with `mvn clean install` the spring context load the properties from the `evn` variables and not the properties file even if we specify the active profile.

We want that spring context load the properties from `application.properties` and not `env` variables.

Comment: I don't think you can influence the precedence of where Spring will load the configuration from. Can you describe why you're using the ENV variables in the first place and can't replace those with eg. a spring profile-specific application.properties file?

Comment: we have the notion of spring profile and it work if i run the build from the IDE like STS but when i run from the terminal the properties loaded from env variables.
for why we use env vars me too i don't have an idea why they do that cause its an application  of maintenance!

Comment: Could you maybe wrap your build command line in a script which unsets the env variables in question? Something like "unset YOUR_VAR; mvn clean install"

Comment: Yes we have this solution but it is not the perfect solution